# Nestjs, Docker, Postgres and TypeOrmModule: ERROR [TypeOrmModule] Unable to connect to the database

Tags: postgresql, docker, nestjs

Like the title says I can' get my nest.js app to connect to postgres.

My `app.module`:

```
import { Module } from '@nestjs/common';
import { TypeOrmModule } from '@nestjs/typeorm';
import { AppController } from './app.controller';
import { AppService } from './app.service';
import { CoffeesModule } from './coffees/coffees.module';

@Module({
  imports: [
    CoffeesModule,
    TypeOrmModule.forRoot({
      type: 'postgres', // type of our database
      host: 'localhost', // database host
      port: 5432, // database host
      username: 'postgres', // username
      password: 'pass123', // user password
      database: 'postgres', // name of our database,
      autoLoadEntities: true, // models will be loaded automatically 
      synchronize: true, // your entities will be synced with the database(recommended: disable in prod)
    }),
  ],
  controllers: [AppController],
  providers: [AppService],
})

export class AppModule {}
```

My `docker-compose.yml`:

```
version: "3"
services:
  db:
    image:  postgres
    restart: always 
    ports:
      - "5432:5432"
    environment:
       POSTGRES_PASSWORD: pass123
```

Error message:

> [Nest] 570  - 07/28/2023, 4:41:29 PM   ERROR [TypeOrmModule] Unable to connect to the database. Retrying (1)...
> Error: connect ECONNREFUSED 127.0.0.1:5432
> at TCPConnectWrap.afterConnect [as oncomplete] (node:net:1494:16)
> Blockquote

I ran `docker-compose -f docker-compose.yml up` prior and Essentially I got:

[image]

What on earth am I doing wrong?

Comment: I see you're starting postgres from your `docker-compose.yaml`, but where is your nest.js app running?

Comment: Thanks for responding! In another terminal window in vscode.

Comment: Are you able to connect to postgres from the command line using e.g. the `psql` client?

Comment: After the 10th connection attempt, what is the error reported?

Comment: @larsks I'm on wsl (AL2023) how would I install `psql`?

Comment: @JayMcDoniel I get `Error: connect ECONNREFUSED 127.0.0.1:5432
    at TCPConnectWrap.afterConnect [as oncomplete] (node:net:1494:16)`

Comment: There should be more information than that'

Comment: This is a tut which involves `docker-compose` I'm thinking that's the problem.

Answer (score 1):

Since you are running the app via Docker it is running in it's own network has a different `localhost` than the one you have on your local machine.

Please modify: `host: 'localhost'` -> `host: 'db'` so that value for 'host' references the service name of your postgres service from docker-compose